# JQ: How to efficiently find root nodes given objects each referring to immediate parent

Tags: json, algorithm, tree, jq

I have a stream of objects looking like this:

```
{
  "id": "123456789012345",
  "parent_id": "123456789012344"
}
{
  "id": "123456789012346",
  "parent_id": "123456789012345"
}
{
  "id": "123456789012344"
}
```

What is the most computationally efficient way to lookup and add `root_id` attribute to those objects that have `parent_id` set?

E.g. desired output for the above input would be:

```
{
  "id": "123456789012345",
  "parent_id": "123456789012344"
  "root_id": "123456789012344"
}
{
  "id": "123456789012346",
  "parent_id": "123456789012345",
  "root_id": "123456789012344"
}
{
  "id": "123456789012344",
  "root_id": "123456789012344"
}
```

That is:

- for the second object (IDed 12345678901234**6**), immediate parent is 123456789012345 (which is first object)
- in turn, for the first object, parent is 12345678901234**4** -- which is grandparent for second object (12345678901234**6**)
- and 12345678901234**4** has no parents, therefore it becomes a root node for itself and all the other objects it is a (grand)parent for.

---

I [used to consider](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/526241/bash-how-to-efficiently-find-root-nodes-given-set-of-parent-child) using a bash script, but ideally would prefer JQ for a problem I have in hand today.

Comment: Could you add a proper input to represent your problem and show an expected output for the same?

Comment: So what @Inian is saying, a [mre] is needed so we can 'play' with the data to help you find a solution. Consider reading [ask] if you have any further questions.

Comment: `0stone0` `Inian`: Done.

Comment: @wassrubleff: Why does the second object have `root_id` set to `123456789012344` when `parent_id` is `123456789012345`

Comment: @Inian For second object (IDed 12345678901234**6**), immediate parent is 12345678901234**5** (which is first object).  In turn, for the first object, parent is 12345678901234**4** -- which is grandparent for second object (12345678901234**6**). And 12345678901234**4** has no parents, therefore it becomes a root node for itself and all the other objects it is a (grand)parent for.

Answer (score 1):

The following is fairly efficient, and for the given input produces the desired result,
but the requirements are unclear so please do not use the following blindly.

The following assumes that jq is invoked with the -n command-line option.

```
# Try to find the origin_id of the input object, given a dictionary of objects indexed by .id
def origin_id($dict):
  .parent_id as $p
  | if $p == null then .id
    elif .origin_id then .origin_id
    else $dict[.parent_id] | origin_id($dict)
    end;
    
INDEX(inputs| if .parent_id == null then .origin_id=.id else . end; .id) as $ids
| $ids[]
| .origin_id = origin_id($ids)
```